# How to remove consecutive links from a webpage?

Tags: php, regex

I wish to remove consecutive links on a webpage

Here is a sample

```
<div style="font-family: Arial;">
    <br>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="http://google.com">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="http://google.com">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</a>
    Google is a search
    <a href="http://www.google.com">engine</a>
```

In the above html I want to remove the first 2 A tags  and not the third one (My script should only remove consecutive  tags)

Comment: Great! What have you tried? Why do you think that regex will solve this for you? Is this an actual requirement, or will you be removing it from the tags?

Comment: Hey the question has been editing!! This is not what I asked for !!

Comment: @Shan How do you define "consecutive a tags"? Separated by whitespace and / or `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Two consecutive <A> tags, they should be not be removed if there is some text between them like "<A></a> TextText<A></a>" 

They should be removed only if they are like this "<a></a>&nbsp<a></a>" or "<a></a> <a></a>"

Comment: The only edits have been to fix your formatting and English.

Comment: @Tom The entire question was changed by someone without my knowledge..

Comment: @Shan: Look at the revision history. The formatting and English were fixed and your wording clarified. (OK, to be fair, the input data was changed.. which was silly, @J0HN!) Now, please answer the question I posted to you in my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a regex for this. They are extremely powerful but not for finding this kind of "consecutive" tags.

I suggest you use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Then you can browse the HTML as a tree.
Here is an example (not tested):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// avoid blank nodes when parsing
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
// reads HTML in a string, loadHtmlFile() also exists
$doc->loadHTML($html);
// find all "a" tags
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
// remove the first link
$parent = $links->item(0)->parentNode;
$parent->removeChild($links->item(0));
// test the node following the second link
if ($links->item(1)->nextSibling->nodeType != XML_TEXT_NODE) {
    // delete this node ...
}
// print the modified HTML
// See DOMDocument's attributes if you want to format the output
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```